# Using Sping Beans on abstract classes

Tags: java, spring, abstract-class

I'm looking for a pattern to simplify bean creation for a team of developers.
For now, I've been trying to use abstract classes like this:

```java
public abstract class BaseClass {
    
    @Bean
    public BeanA generateBeanA() {
        ...
        return beanA;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanB generateBeanB() {
        ...
        return beanB;
    }
    
}
```

The idea behind: I provide the BaseClass and I'd like developers to extend it many times. For each extension, every beans should be generated. But this approach doesn't work : for each extension, developers have to redeclare beans for 2 reasons :

- bean declaration is not inherited
- to avoid name clashing, they have to name beans manually in each extension

Is there a better pattern that would allow the following?

- centralized bean naming (ie: the developer declare a base name in the extension and every bean of the extension is renamed accordingly: ${baseName}${beanName} )
- overriden beans would be declared (instead of parent version)
- parent beans would be declared if not overriden

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to configure beans in `Spring` container:

- Declare them using XML configuration.
- Declare beans using the `@Bean`
  annotation in a configuration class.
- Mark the class with one of the
  annotations from the `org.springframework.stereotype` package, and
  leave the rest to component scanning.

So, the way you declare `Spring` bean is wrong.

IMHO, let the developers declare beans as they want, and they just `@Autowired` them or something.

Please continue by reading [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

Comment: I understand that's not the common way to declare beans. But the team has hundred of them to create based on common definition. These beans will be consumed by an external library on which we don't have control. So letting developers creating all of them manually is not an option here